# PgAdmin won't allow RAISE NOTICE

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

When I try to use RAISE NOTICE in a Query tool in PgAdmin I just get "`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RAISE"`".  This is stopping defining a stored procedure which uses `RAISE NOTICE`.

I have simply typed the following into a Query Tool window:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'Bob';
```

I am using PgAdmin 6.3 (the latest), just updated from v4.5 which had the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RAISE is part of pl/pgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html), Postgres's default procedural language. It is not available in a direct SQL context, or any function or stored procedure defined with `LANGUAGE sql` rather than `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.

If you're used to a different DBMS like MySQL or SQL Server, you might expect to have procedural code (variables, conditionals, loops, etc) available by default, but that's not how Postgres works. In order to use procedural code, you need to be inside a function, stored procedure, or [DO statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html).

Comment: Thanks, I was coming from SqlServer and didn't know that!

Comment: Is there any way to print a notice from a query tool window?  It's useful for testing code before making it into a stored procedure.

Comment: @AntWaters If what you're doing is just plain SQL, then you can presumably just use SELECT; but if it's actually procedural - with an IF, or a loop, or a variable, etc - then it's not going to work without at least a DO statement anyway.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to test a conditional was going to work

Comment: @AntWaters Then whether you can raise a notice doesn't matter - you can't have a conditional in plain SQL anyway.

Comment: ok, I will have to look at the Debugger